# Redirect from old domain to new domain without the extention

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a domain whhich i want to redirect to a new domain. I want the request to stay the same but my following code is adding the .php extention to it. The following code is what i have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldomain.eu [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.eu/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.eu [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.eu/$1 [L,R=301]
```

When i go to the following url: www.oldomain.eu/samplepage it is redirecting me to www.newdomain.eu/samplepage.php

How could i prevent this from adding the .php to the url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like mod_negotiation interferring. Try adding a:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

above your rules.

Comment: Still not working, i have tried the line you given me. But therefore the first line was "Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews All" and underneath the rewrite rules. The rest of the file is empty.

Comment: @R.Schaaphuizen remove the `Multiviews` from your `Options` line.

Comment: Great! that's working, could have tried that myself of course. It is only adding a / after the url but that is no problem.